Power Automate Approval action - Can I replicate the "Approve/Reject - Everyone Must Approve" with custom responses?
I have a requirement for a Power Automate flow (SharePoint Library) in which the Start and Wait for an Approval action - "Approve/Reject - Everyone Must Approve" meets all of my requirements, except one.  Currently only the Requestor can Cancel a request, but my requirement is to also give that option to the Approvers.  That option would basically serve as a "skip me" response.  I would need all Approvers to either "Approve" or "Cancel" in order to move it along to the Final Approval stage, and only one "Reject" would end the flow.  The "Custom Responses: Wait for All Responses" almost gives me what I need - except it will wait for All Responses, even if the first response Rejects the request.
So, is there a way I can customize this to meet the requirements?  I want to avoid having to build a powerapp, and require the Approvers to re-open the submitted form to provide a response.
Thanks!

Two are many ways how to achieve it - one I can recommend is following - tap into Dataverse table where approvals are stored. You can start approval Everyone must approve and create new flow that has a trigger When rows is added, modified or deleted that monitors responses - if any response is Rejected, cancel the approval process.
References:
Microsoft docs : Trigger flows when a row is added, modified, or deleted
Step-by-step article on approval request delegation
This approach requires premium license - without it, is very challenging to fulfill your requirements without "cutting corners" and compromising UX.
